# Django application with user images hosted in Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I want to create a web application where user can upload their own images and they will be hosted on Amazon S3... but the problem is that I will need them resized (and croped) in various sizes (that can be eventually changed when design of the site is changed?).

What is the right way to do it... upload file to S3 and then create all the resized versions (like WordPress)?

Or may be create template tag which specifies needed size and create the images dynamically and also host them on S3. Will it be too slow because for every image I will need to check doest it exist and eventually create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into using [sorl-thumbnai](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail) which supports [django's storage backends](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/) so you are free to switch to a [backend using S3](http://code.welldev.org/django-storages/wiki/S3Storage). In this case it would be recommendable to have your django installation run on EC2, which will grant you a good connection to S3.

Comment: Do I need local image store (Pluggable Key Value Store support?) or resized images can also be hosted on S3?

Comment: You can host everything on S3. The Key Value Store is only used to store the filename - you can either use the db or redis for that. https://docs.google.com/drawings/edit?id=1wlE4LkQpzXd2a2Nxfjt6_j5NG7889dzMyf0V-xPAJSE&hl=en&pli=1

Comment: Can you help me also with this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674931/django-sorl-thumbnail-and-hosting-image-files-on-my-own-file-server